# Refactoring an activerecord method in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, refactoring, find

Can this events method be re-factored and simplified?

```
class Manager < User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :customers

  def events
    Event.joins(:customers => :managers).where(:users => { :id => self }).select("DISTINCT(events.id), events.description, events.created_at")
  end

end
```

I was hoping I could build the query on top of the Manager instance I currently have, but seem unable to do this. I tried the following, but got an error

```
def events
  customers.joins(:events).select("DISTINCT(events.id), events.description, events.created_at")
end
```

and

```
current_user.events
```

But this results in MySQL error:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT(events.id), events.description, events.created_at FROM `customers` INNER' at line 1: SELECT `customers`.*, DISTINCT(events.id), events.description, events.created_at FROM `customers` INNER JOIN `customers_events` ON `customers_events`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`id` INNER JOIN `events` ON `events`.`id` = `customers_events`.`event_id` INNER JOIN `customers_managers` ON `customers`.`id` = `customers_managers`.`customer_id` WHERE `customers_managers`.`manager_id` = 27 ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Comment: You could at least say what the error is, and what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html), the DISTINCT keyword must come before the select_expr:

```
SELECT foo.*, DISTINCT(foo.id)
```

will give you that error.

```
SELECT distinct(foo.id), foo.*
```

will work.  Try this:

```
customers.select("DISTINCT(events.id), events.description, events.created_at").joins(:events)
```

However, if all you're trying to do is to get the unique events per user (I assume that's what the DISTINCT is for), you could just use

```
current_user.events.group("events.id")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Thilo, unfortunately I get exactly the same error for your first solution. And your second solution results in an error as a user only has events through a customer.

Comment: Well, I don't have your DB nor model structure so I can't provide an exact solution. The gist is, don't use DISTINCT if you can avoid it - use group(). If you have to use DISTINCT, you have to find a way to chain your active record scopes to that the DISTINCT is the first part of the select statement.

Comment: I have been experimenting with the generated SQL, the problem seems to be with the SQL "SELECT `customers`.*" as the customers table is not being included.

Comment: In the error message that you included, the query includes a join on customers. Try to copy the full query to your console - you should see that if you reverse the order and put the DISTINCT part to the front, it should work.

Comment: It seems the .select is being ignored, I think this is a bug with Rails 3.1

Comment: Thilo - Yes, putting the DISTINCT first makes the query work! The only problem i have now is why the SQL includes "SELECT customers.*" when "customers" is not mentioned inside my .select method.

Comment: Because of your explicitly joining with the customers table. I suggest reading up on ActiveRecord scopes and method chaining. This is not pure SQL, Rails is doing a lot of under the hood SQL magic.